# cmake obtain source list

Tags: c++, dependencies, cmake

I have a big project already building under cmake. I am looking for a way to obtain the list of source files and their dependent header files to create a new target (in example etags for Emacs). I tried to find the answer on my own but it seems to not be that easy.

The ideal soultion would be something like that:

```
add_executable(my_project <some list of source files and libraries defined in different directories>)
add_custom_target(tags
  COMMAND etags <list of all *.cpp and *.h files used in 'my_project' target>
  DEPENDS <list of all *.cpp and *h used in 'my_project' target>
  COMMENT "Creates source code tags for Emacs")
```

Do you maybe know how to make 'tags' target import all dependencies from 'my_project' target without the need to rewrite all cmake configuration files in all directories?

Answer (score 16):

With command `get_target_property` and property SOURCES and eventually PUBLIC_HEADER or PRIVATE_HEADER?

```
get_target_property(MY_PROJECT_SOURCES my_project SOURCES)
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work for simple cases. However if you have subdirectories with `add_library(SOME_LIB)` and then my executable is linked with `target_link_libraries(my_project SOME_LIB)` those dependecies does not presented.

Moreover I cannot make PUBLIC_/PRIVATE_ HEADER to work. Is it possible at all to get dependecies (ie. headers) while compiling *.cpp and them obtain them in a variable?

Comment: according to https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html try use INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES  for include path